# Signed url not working for cloudfront streaming with Flowplayer

Tags: amazon-s3, flowplayer, amazon-cloudfront

I created cloudfront distribution with signed url by referring to the link: http://beckelman.net/2010/03/30/policy-signing-in-c-for-streaming-private-content-from-amazon-cloudfront/

Below are my questions

1. what should be passed to 'path' parameter to get signed url in 'CloudFrontStreamingUrl()' method? The s3 path like :
   https://abc.s3.amazonaws.com/xyz.flv or rtmp://pqr.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/abc.flv?
2. For below flowplayer set up 'netconnection url' will be signed url? or the physical file name will be signed and passed to player

   ```
   flowplayer("rtmpPlayer", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.8.swf", {

       // configure the required plugins
       plugins:  {

           // the RTMP plugin
           rtmp: {
               url: "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.8.swf",

               // netConnectionUrl has our CloudFront domain name + 'cfx/st'
               netConnectionUrl: 'rtmp://s3b78u0kbtx79q.cloudfront.net/cfx/st'
           }
       },

       clip: {
           // use the RTMP plugin
           provider: 'rtmp'
       }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be regression in the latest release.  I had the same problem and had to roll back to version 3.2.5.